# unable to use case statement in inner sql query

Tags: sql

From the below sql, im able to get the output as status and AVG_PROD_COUNT.

my question is when the account_num = 'A128' or 'A126', I need to use
" (**dpc.product_id = cpp.product_id OR dpc.product_id   =999)** ".I tried using case statments.I am new to sql unable to get the output.can any one please help on this.

### Cpp table is

account_num

pakage_id

product_id

---

SELECT avg.status,

```
SUM(avg.AVG_PROD_COUNT) AVG_PROD_COUNT
FROM
(SELECT
  DECODE(dpc.product_id,999,'SUSPEND','ACTIVE') status,
  dpc.product_id,
  dpc.package_id,
  ROUND(SUM(dpc.product_count)/ (to_date( '$billDate' ,'YYYYMMDD') - add_months(to_date( '$billDate' ,'YYYYMMDD'), -1)), 2) AVG_PROD_COUNT
FROM dailyproductcount dpc,      
  cust_pkg_prod cpp
WHERE dpc.rating_acct_nbr = cpp.account_num   
AND dpc.rating_acct_nbr not in('A128','A126') 
AND dpc.activity_dat BETWEEN add_months(to_date( '$billDate' ,'YYYYMMDD'), -1) AND to_date( '$billDate' ,'YYYYMMDD')-1
AND (dpc.product_id = cpp.package_id
OR dpc.product_id   =999) 
AND dpc.package_id  = cpp.package_id
GROUP BY dpc.product_id,
  dpc.package_id
) AVG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The sql above won't work because there is no "GROUP BY avg.status" in the parent query
2. As I understand you need something like this in a WHERE condition (I assume you use Oracle):

   ...
   WHERE dpc.rating_acct_nbr = cpp.account_num
   AND dpc.activity_dat BETWEEN add_months(to_date( '$billDate' ,'YYYYMMDD'), -1) AND to_date( '$billDate' ,'YYYYMMDD')-1
   AND dpc.package_id  = cpp.package_id
   AND (dpc.product_id = 999 OR **dpc.product_id = decode(dpc.rating_acct_nbr, 'A126', cpp.product_id, 'A128', cpp.product_id, cpp.package_id)** )
   ...

if you want to use CASE, the condition
"product_id = decode(dpc.rating_acct_nbr, 'A126', cpp.product_id, 'A128', cpp.product_id, cpp.package_id)" will look like:

```
product_id = case when dpc.rating_acct_nbr in ('A126', 'A128') then cpp.product_id else cpp.package_id end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.. I am able to see the output.

Comment: user3274607 can you describe what does it mean in terms of your structure? "get both the 'ACTIVE' and 'SUSPEND'"

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your logic or possibly a typo -

```
(dpc.product_id = cpp.package_id
OR dpc.product_id   =999) 
AND dpc.package_id  = cpp.package_id
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
dpc.package_id  = cpp.package_id
```

This prevents the `dpc.product_id   =999` from ever causing your `where` clause to evaluate as true.

Comment: Functionally that is true, I need to evaluate based on the account_num, if 'A128' or 'A126' then i need to match based on the product_id instead of package_id